# Prepared Statement doesn't exist

Tags: postgresql, sinatra, pgbouncer

Currently running a simple sinatra app, using passenger, and using pgbouncer for connection pooling to a database on the same server as the app.  Currently I am intermittently getting a PG error that the prepared statement "a\d" doesn't exist.

```
A PG::Error occurred in #: 
ERROR: prepared statement "a2" does not exist
```

the ruby code that is executed before the error

```
def self.get_ownership_record(id, key)
  self.where("user_id=? AND key=?", id, key ).first 
end
```

pgbouncer config

```
; #########################################################
; ############# SECTION HEADER [DATABASES] ################
; #########################################################

[databases]

fakedatabase=fake

[pgbouncer]

; ----- Generic Settings --------------------------
; -------------------------------------------------
logfile=/opt/local/var/log/pgbouncer/pgbouncer.log
pidfile=/opt/local/var/run/pgbouncer/pgbouncer.pid
listen_addr=*
listen_port=5444

; unix_socket_dir=/tmp
user=_webuser
auth_file=/Users/Shared/data/global/pg_auth
auth_type=trust
pool_mode=transaction
; max_client_conn=100
; default_pool_size=20
; reserve_pool_size=0
; reserve_pool_timeout=5
; server_round_robin=0

; ----- Log Settings ------------------------------
; -------------------------------------------------
; syslog=0
; syslog_ident=pgbouncer
; syslog_facility=daemon
; log_connections=1
; log_disconnections=1
; log_pooler_errors=1

; ----- Console Access Control --------------------
; -------------------------------------------------
admin_users=admin,nagios
; -------------------------------------------------
; server_reset_query=DISCARD ALL;
 server_check_delay=0
 server_check_query=SELECT 1;
; server_lifetime=3600
; server_idle_timeout=600
; server_connect_timeout=600
; server_login_retry=15
```

Is my only solution, to turn off prepared statements?

database.yml

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: fakedatabase
  username: admin
  host: localhost
  port: 5444
  reconnect: true
  prepared_statements: false
```

**EDIT**

I have updated the pgbouncer.ini to use session pooling

`pool_mode=session`

and uncommented

`server_reset_query=DISCARD ALL;`

and I am still seemingly, randomly getting errors involving prepared statements, but this time

```
An ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid occurred in #: 

PG::Error: ERROR: bind message supplies 2 parameters, but prepared statement "a1" requires 0
```

I have turned on statement level logging in my postgresql logs and will report back with more details if possible.

Comment: I had this problem under rails console. Solution was simple, I need to restart console ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

follwing Richard Huxton advice, and after some trial and error.

my final setup looks like

`database.yml`

had to set `prepared_statements` to `true`

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: fakedatabase
  username: admin
  host: localhost
  port: 5444
  reconnect: true
  prepared_statements: true
```

`pgbouncer.ini`

had to uncomment `server_reset_query=DISCARD ALL;`

and set `pool_mode=session`

```
; #########################################################
; ############# SECTION HEADER [DATABASES] ################
; #########################################################

[databases]

fakedatabase=fake

[pgbouncer]

; ----- Generic Settings --------------------------
; -------------------------------------------------
logfile=/opt/local/var/log/pgbouncer/pgbouncer.log
pidfile=/opt/local/var/run/pgbouncer/pgbouncer.pid
listen_addr=*
listen_port=5444

; unix_socket_dir=/tmp
user=_webuser
auth_file=/Users/Shared/data/global/pg_auth
auth_type=trust
pool_mode=session
; max_client_conn=100
; default_pool_size=20
; reserve_pool_size=0
; reserve_pool_timeout=5
; server_round_robin=0

; ----- Log Settings ------------------------------
; -------------------------------------------------
; syslog=0
; syslog_ident=pgbouncer
; syslog_facility=daemon
; log_connections=1
; log_disconnections=1
; log_pooler_errors=1

; ----- Console Access Control --------------------
; -------------------------------------------------
admin_users=admin,nagios
; -------------------------------------------------
server_reset_query=DISCARD ALL;
server_check_delay=0
server_check_query=SELECT 1;
; server_lifetime=3600
; server_idle_timeout=600
; server_connect_timeout=600
; server_login_retry=15
```

**basically allow prepared statements in a session pool mode with the default server reset query.**

Answer (score 1):

In my case access to postgres directory and run "DEALLOCATE ALL" resolve the problem.

If you use heroku, like this

```
> heroku pg:psql -a app_name
app_name::DATABASE=> DEALLOCATE ALL
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [reading the FAQ](https://pgbouncer.github.io/faq.html) would help? Unless you have a good reason not to, session-pooling should be sensible.

Comment: That link is dead now

Comment: I would never have found that!

Answer (score 0):

Since PgBouncer 1.21.0 now supports protocol level named prepared statements, which is probably what the Ruby client uses. You can turn this support on by setting `max_prepared_statements` to a non-zero value. For details check the docs: https://www.pgbouncer.org/config.html#max_prepared_statements

Answer (score -1):

You can use transaction pooling, provided that you `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE` the prepared query inside the same transaction (to avoid pgBouncer running the `server_reset_query` in between).