# "ERROR: cached plan must not change result type" when mixing DDL with SELECT via JDBC

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc

I'm experiencing an interesting issue with PostgreSQL via JDBC (couldn't reproduce it outside of JDBC yet) where I'm getting an

> “ERROR: cached plan must not change result type”

The simplest way to reproduce this issue is by using the following code:

```
Connection c = getConnection();
c.setAutoCommit(true);
List<String> statements = Arrays.asList(
    "create table t(a int)",
    "select * from t",
    "alter table t add b int",
    "select * from t",
    "alter table t add c int",
    "select * from t",
    "alter table t add d int",
    "select * from t",
    "alter table t add e int",
    "select * from t",
    "alter table t add f int",
    "select * from t"
);

for (String statement : statements)
    try (PreparedStatement s = c.prepareStatement(statement)) {
        System.out.println(s);
        s.execute();
    }
```

The fact that the following code works fine leads to me assuming this is a very subtle bug in the JDBC driver (note, I've simply removed the sixth DDL statement in the batch):

```
Connection c = getConnection();
c.setAutoCommit(true);
List<String> statements = Arrays.asList(
    "create table t(a int)",
    "select * from t",
    "alter table t add b int",
    "select * from t",
    "alter table t add c int",
    "select * from t",
    "alter table t add d int",
    "select * from t",
    "alter table t add e int",
    "select * from t"
);

for (String statement : statements)
    try (PreparedStatement s = c.prepareStatement(statement)) {
        System.out.println(s);
        s.execute();
    }
```

It would appear that discarding all cached plans via [`DISCARD ALL`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-discard.html) should work, but it makes things worse:

```
Connection c = getConnection();
c.setAutoCommit(true);
List<String> statements = Arrays.asList(
    "create table t(a int)",
    "select * from t",
    "alter table t add b int",
    "select * from t",
    "alter table t add c int",
    "select * from t",
    "alter table t add d int",
    "select * from t",
    "alter table t add e int",
    "select * from t",
    "alter table t add f int",
    "discard all",
    "select * from t"
);

for (String statement : statements)
    try (PreparedStatement s = c.prepareStatement(statement)) {
        System.out.println(s);
        s.execute();
    }
```

[I'm running into another error message](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20150503/521799)

> “ERROR: prepared statement "S_1" doesn't exist”

Does anyone know a workaround? Or a pointer documenting this bug? Interesting bit, it seems to be related to the [default prepare threshold of 5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8104595/521799)

Comment: Have you tried with other variable names?  Perhaps `f` is some sort of reserved keyword?  Also, complete stack traces would be helpful.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: It is, but this is the simplified version of the real problem where removing the prepared statement from the game is less easy

Comment: @aguibert ;) Good point. I tried, but no. The real version uses quotes around names anyway...

Comment: have you checked this question?  Looks like a possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783813/postgres-8-3-error-cached-plan-must-not-change-result-type

Comment: @aguibert: I have indeed, and it isn't a duplicate, at least not from the accepted answer (by the OP) which claims that stuff happened in parallel. In my case, all statements are executed in a single session.

Comment: @LukasEder The connection details may be useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be related to [PostgreSQL's `PREPARE_THRESHOLD`, which defaults to 5 for the JDBC driver](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8104595/521799).

Setting it to zero will solve / work around this particular issue:

```
 ((PGConnection) connection).setPrepareThreshold(0);
```

[More info is also available in this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32297503/521799)

Comment: You can also change this through an URL parameter: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/94/connect.html#connection-parameters

Answer (score 3):

Disabling prepared statements is too drastic an action to fix this issue.  You can now solve the specific problem by setting `autosave=conservative` on the pgjdbc connection settings, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48536394/924597